# convert uint8_t array to char array in c

Tags: c, arrays, hash

Initially I want to convert this `uint8_t` array to a `char` array in c. I have been a little stuck trying to resolve this problem. My first alternative solution is to copy another type value to the temporary one, copy the tmp value to a writable char, and then remove tmp value from memory. By the way this is used to accompany a blake hash function. Here is my code snippet:

```
char * bl(char *input)
{
    uint8_t  output[64];
    char msg[]= "";
    char *tmp;

    int dInt;

    memset(output,0,64);
    tmp = (char*) malloc(64);
    if (!tmp){
            exit( 1);
    }

    dInt = strlen(input);

    if (dInt > 0xffff){
            exit( 1);
    }
    uint8_t data[dInt];

    memset(data,0, dInt);
    strlcpy(data,input,dInt);
    uint64_t dLen =dInt;
    blake512_hash(output, data,dLen);

    int k;
    for (k=0;k<64;k++){
            tmp[k] = output[k];  //does this "copy" is buggy code?
    }

    memcpy(msg, tmp,64);
    //so here I can to delete tmp value
    // I dont want there were left unused value in memory
    // delete tmp;  
    free(tmp);

    return  msg;
}
```

I think the code above is still not efficient, so what are your opinion, hints and the fixes?
Thank you very much before!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, you should never return a pointer to a local variable since the variable will be destroyed by the time the function exits. You should probably want to pass the output array to `bl` function and use that to output the string.

For most cases(if uint8_t IS char, which is usually the case), `memcpy(msg, output, 64)` should be sufficient. If you want to be strict about it(quite frankly `blake512_hash` shouldn't return `uint8_t` array in the first place if you are expecting `char` array as the output all the time), you could simply call `msg[k] = (char)tmp[k]` in your for loop and remove `memcpy`.

Comment: I want to use this function later to be called in Python, that's way I'm expecting this funtion later will return an string value.

Comment: @user1309539 Yes but you should still fix the problem i mentioned in my answer. You simply cannot return the pointer to a local variable.

Comment: then tmp variable would be useless. what to be copied from tmp variable, since tmp variable is only allocated char not the output one ?

Comment: @user1309539 you don't need tmp variable since you can simply copy the output to `msg`

Answer (score 0):

A bit much is wrong here.

```
dInt = strlen(input) + 1; // dInt is the size of the string including the terminating '\0'.
```

`strlcpy` indeed uses the size, not strlen.

msg = tmp; and not freeing tmp. As msg is const char* "" (in C++ terms).

Comment: umh, yes thanks. anymore wrong again, please give your suggestion about above code, thanks :)